# FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a variable to reference a Firestore document.

```
const userRef = doc(db, 'users', uid)
```

and use it by adding a Realtime listener

```
onSnapshot(userRef,  (doc) => {
        if (doc.exists()){
            setCode(code = doc.data().keycode)
        } else {
            setCode(code = 'N/A')
        }
    })
```

But it gets this error

```
FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
```

At first, I thought it was because the uid is incorrect, so I hard coded it, and still has the same error.

Here's the full code, it's a react component. I imported the firebase config from App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { onSnapshot, doc, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

function Transaction(uid, firebase) {
    const db = getFirestore(firebase);

    let [amount, setAmount] = useState('')
    let [target, setTarget] = useState('')
    let [code, setCode] = useState('')

    const userRef = doc(db, 'users', uid)
    
    const sendNum = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Send Num')
    }

    const generateCode = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Generate Code')
    }


    onSnapshot(userRef,  (doc) => {
        if (doc.exists()){
            setCode(code = doc.data().keycode)
        } else {
            setCode(code = 'N/A')
        }
    })

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={sendNum}>
                <input style={{ width: 200 }}value={amount} onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)} type="number" placeholder='Amount'/>
                <input style={{ width: 200 }} value={target} onChange={(e) => setTarget(e.target.value)} type="number" placeholder='Keycode'/>
                <br />
                <button className='btn' type='submit'>Send</button>
            </form>
 
            <section>
                <h2>{code}</h2>
                <button className='btn' onClick={generateCode} type='submit'>Generate Code</button>
            </section>
        </>
    )
}

export default Transaction
```

I used React Router and passed the props in there.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAKLyeY2FbjFDD57Kp9sGDi8uHg3neXxjI",
  authDomain: "digitots-dev.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "digitots-dev",
  storageBucket: "digitots-dev.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "150130182744",
  appId: "1:150130182744:web:216e77264273772c94182d",
  measurementId: "G-RJT8Q1LSXZ"
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

let uid = ''

function App() {
  
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <header>
        <Router>
          <Nav />
          
          <Switch>
            
            <Route path='/' exact component={MainView} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path='/shop' component={Shop}/>
            <Route path='/admin' component={Admin}/>
            
            <Route
              path='/portal'
              render={(props) => (
                <Transaction {...props}  db={db} uid={uid} firebase={firebaseConfig}/>
              )}
            />
            

          </Switch>
           
        </Router>
      </header>

      
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the error says `Expected first argument to collection()` even if you pass invalid arguments in `doc()`. That being said, `db` is undefined or is not an instance of Firestore. Make sure you are importing `db` from the file where you initialize Firestore or it's defined in same file:

```
import { getFirestore, doc } from "firebase/firestore"

const db = getFirestore(app) // const app = initializeApp(fireConfig)

const userRef = doc(db, 'users', uid)
```

---

About the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProvider' of undefined` error:

```
<Transaction {...props}  db={db} uid={uid} firebase={firebaseConfig}/>
```

You are passing the Firebase config (a JSON object) into `getFirestore()` as a parameter while it expects the Firebase app instance.

```
// Incorrect
const db = getFirestore(firebase);


// Correct
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
```

Change the Transaction component to:

```
<Transaction {...props} uid={uid} firebase={firebaseApp}/>
```

Comment: I did that and now it just has this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProvider' of undefined

Comment: @PathonScript can you please update your question with latest code you have and screenshot of error? That error seem to be a somewhere else.

Comment: Sure thing, I did :)

Comment: @PathonScript I cannot see any screenshot of errors. Can you share one including the logs ? We need to check where it is coming from first.

Comment: oh ok, I completely forgot about that.

Comment: @PathonScript now I need to know what if that firebase var being passed in transaction function. Please share the part of code which call this function and we can see what firebase is defined as.

Comment: the const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp). Do you mean in the App.js or in the Transaction.js ?

Comment: @PathonScript both.

Comment: so in the Transaction.js is const db = getFirestore(firebase) only, right?

Comment: because if you pass a prop firebase = {firebaseApp}, I think it'll be used as 'firebase'.

Comment: @PathonScript right now you are passing `firebaseConfig` in props. Yes just make sure `firebaseApp` is passed in `getFirestore()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236736/discussion-between-pathonscript-and-dharmaraj).